# jQuery resize text within elements

Tags: jquery, resize

Ok, have successful code for resizing `td` elements within a table, on page load, to a percentage of the users screen as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var xWidth = $(window).width();
    $("td.tablecol_0").animate({ 
        width: (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + 'px',
        minWidth: (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + 'px',
        maxWidth: (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + 'px'}, 1000);
    $("td.tablecol_1").animate({ 
        width: (xWidth * (35 / 100)) + 'px',
        minWidth: (xWidth * (35 / 100)) + 'px',
        maxWidth: (xWidth * (35 / 100)) + 'px'}, 1000);
    $("td.tablecol_2").animate({ 
        width: (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + 'px',
        minWidth: (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + 'px',
        maxWidth: (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + 'px'}, 1000);
});
```

So, this works according to the windows width:  15%, 35%, and 15% (for 3 columns).  Works great.  However, I'd like to have the inside content of this also resize...  Like all elements within it.  I would like them to resize accordingly.

How can I do this quickly and easily in jQuery using the following code above?

Comment: You're going to have to give more details. A functional jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) showing what you are trying to apply this to would be the most help. If you just want to change the text size though, add textSize: (whatever) to your animate calls. Or if they're blocks like divs, just give them a CSS style which uses percentage sizes (I'm not sure why you didn't do this for the cells too?)

Comment: Well if I give the `td` elements a percentage value in css on them naturally, like:  25%, 50%, and 25%, will it also make the text inside of the elements bigger automatically?

Comment: The text *bounds* will grow with it if that's what you mean. If you want the *font size* to change, use the jQuery to change fontSize.

Comment: Yeah, I would like the `font size` within the `td` element to change also, but how to figure out how much it should change to?  Like I'll need to calculate the new `font-size` somehow.  But how?

Comment: You triggered my interest, so I made this test which automatically calculates a text size based on the content: http://jsfiddle.net/vqbCL/2/ (try resizing the pane). I do *not* recommend using this in a big table though (not very efficient), and it may break in IE/whatever.

Comment: Wow, Awesome, thanks.  That's really what I needed, but why did you create an empty `<div>` tag?

Comment: The div is to put text in so that it can be measured (in the table cells it would wrap around so any measurement will be wrong). Notice that the div has white-space:no-wrap and overflow:hidden, and is used by the javascript. But please remember that this is a gimmick; it doesn't allow zooming in on the page and (as-is) may not work in all browsers

Comment: Yeah, I actually have tried this, and ouch, looks terrible, so I'm not using it.  But thanks just the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `font-size` property in some `percent` value, just like,

```
table{ font-size:50% }
```

Using `jQuery` you can do it like,

```
$('table').css('font-size', '100%')
```

Or

```
$('table').css('font-size', '70%')
```

Or individually for a `td`

```
$("td.tablecol_0").animate({ 
    'width' : (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + 'px',
    'minWidth' : (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + 'px',
    'maxWidth' : (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + 'px',
    'fontSize' : (xWidth * (15 / 100)) + '%'
}, 1000);
```

If you set `100%` for all `tds` then you can simply use `$(`table`).css('fontSize', '100%')`.

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2xx6F/3/)

Comment: This seems to be the answer according to what he's been saying in comments, but I'll add three things: 1) He really shouldn't use JavaScript to resize the cells, because that's just ugly and inefficient (use css!), 2) Without a very good reason, .css( should be used, not .animate(, and 3) This should be tied to the resize event of the document/body.

Comment: @Dave, I agree with you and that's why I've provided `css` code too, at first.

Comment: Hey, thanks, can you give me an example of how to tie this into the resize event of the document/body?

Comment: @SolomonClosson, Welcome, `$(window).resize(function() {
  // your code
});`